# Python data aggregation on X and Y axes

Tags: python, pandas

Need some help with data aggregaion in Python.

I have a Dataframe with 3 columns and N rows. First two columns contains indices (let it be `X` and `Y`), the last one contains values. The task is to calc a `sum()` of values of third column [corresponding with `(x_i,y_j)`] and write it in the new Dataframe in the intersection of `(x_i,y_j)`

Or, simplier, transform:

```
ind1 ind2 value
 x1  y1    k1
 x2  y1    k2
 x3  y1    k3
 x1  y2    k4
 x2  y2    k5
 x3  y2    k6
```

into some kind of 2d massive

```
      y1  y2
     ________
 x1 |k1  k4
 x2 |k2  k5
 x3 |k3  k6
```

I've tried `pandas.groupby` but didn't found proper solution. So, what should i do?

Comment: You should use `pivot_table`, see [documentation here](http://www.nikgrozev.org/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pivot your data. Example:

```
In [5]: data = {'ind1': ['x1','x2','x3','x1','x2','x3'],
 'ind2': ['y1','y1','y1','y2','y2','y2'],
 'value': ['k1','k2','k3','k4','k5','k6']}

In [6]: pd.DataFrame(data=data)
Out[6]:
  ind1 ind2 value
0   x1   y1    k1
1   x2   y1    k2
2   x3   y1    k3
3   x1   y2    k4
4   x2   y2    k5
5   x3   y2    k6

In [9]: df.pivot(index='ind1', columns='ind2', values='value')
Out[9]:
ind2  y1  y2
ind1
x1    k1  k4
x2    k2  k5
x3    k3  k6
```

You can find more information here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: I believe OP also wanted to sum overlapping values. That would then be a job for `pivot_table`, right?

Comment: yep, I guess that with a `np.sum` as `aggfunc` should work. Would be great if the OP could update his example with some numeric values so that the desired behavior is easier to see.

Comment: Thank you and yes, @IanS is right - i also need to sum values. The dataset is from [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-sales-in-stormy-weather/download/train.csv.zip) and contains following fields: date, store_index, item_index, items_sold. So i need to figure how many items of every type where sold in every store (no matter on which date) and then i want to make a 'heatmap' of that. I've managed what to do with plots in Python, but stuck with data aggregation.

Comment: @IanS, @k-nut thank you much, `pivot_table` worked well